# MTKView not rendering in the right coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I'm developing a drawing app. I use `MTKView` to render the canvas. But for some reason, for only a few users, the pixels are not rendered correctly (pixels have different sizes), the majority of users have no problem with this. Here is my setup:

- Each pixel is rendered as 2 triangle
- `MTKView`'s frame dimensions are always multiple of the canvas size (a 100x100 canvas will have the frame size of 100x100, 200x200, and so on)
- There is a grid to indicate pixels (it's an `UIImageView`), and we can see that they don't align with the pixels).
- There is also a checkerboard pattern in the background which lines up with the pixels but not the grid.

Previously, I had the exact same issue when my view's frame is not a multiple of the canvas size, but I fixed that with the setup above already.

The vertices have accurate coordinates, this is a rendering issue. As you can see in the picture, some pixels are bigger than others.

I tried changing the `contentScaleFactor` to 1, 2, and 3 but none seems to solve the problem.

My `MTKView` setup:

```
    clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
    delegate = renderer
    renderer.setup()
    isOpaque = false
    layer.magnificationFilter = .nearest
    layer.minificationFilter = .nearest
```

Renderer's setup:

```
    let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
    pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm

    pipelineState = try? device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
```

draw method of renderer:

```
    commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
    commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(colorBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
    commandEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(
      type: .triangle,
      indexCount: indexCount,
      indexType: .uint32,
      indexBuffer: indexBuffer,
      indexBufferOffset: 0
    )

    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
```

Metal file:

```
struct VertexOut {
  float4 position [[ position ]];
  half4 color;
};

vertex VertexOut frame_vertex(constant const float2* vertices [[ buffer(0) ]],
                              constant const half4* colors [[ buffer(1) ]],
                              uint v_id [[ vertex_id ]]) {
  VertexOut out;
  out.position = float4(vertices[v_id], 0, 1);
  out.color = colors[v_id / 4];
  return out;
}

fragment half4 frame_fragment(VertexOut v [[ stage_in ]]) {
  half alpha = v.color.a;
  return half4(v.color.r * alpha, v.color.g * alpha, v.color.b * alpha, v.color.a);
}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: This doesn't seem likely to be debuggable without any code shown.

Comment: I've added some code to show my MTKView setup. Thanks

Comment: Anyone, please. I'm desperate